# Flask + Gevent, monkey.patch_all() breaks flask

Tags: python, flask, pyqt5, gevent

I need to run monkey.patch_all() as I have a Flask server in my application in combination with the ValvePython library (I get errors about cannot switch to a different thread otherwise) however I'm encountering a problem.
I've tested this without the ValvePython to ensure the issue didn't strictly pend on that.

How I start the server:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all();
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create PyQt5 app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Flask server
    server = Server('Ryder Engine')

    # Create the custom window (The initialize function creates all the
    # server endpoints dynamically via the add_endpoint function
    window = RyderDisplay()
    window.initialize(server)

    # Run Server
    threading.Thread(target=server.run, daemon=True).start()

    # Start the app
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

My server class:

```
import socket
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

class EndpointAction(object):
    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action
        self.response = Response(status=200, headers={})

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.action(request.get_json())
        return self.response

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.app = Flask(name)

    def run(self, port=9520):
        http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', port), self.app)
        http_server.serve_forever()

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, EndpointAction(handler), methods=['POST'])
```

The main page of the PyQt5 app where one of the endpoints is binded to. This is instantiated inside the Window object. The rest are instantiated through the HomeConfigurationParser class through a json config file.

```
class Home(object):
    # Class constructor
    def __init__(self, window, server : Server):
        self._window = window
        self._client = Client()
        self._server = server

        self._client.subscribeToRyderEngine()
        server.add_endpoint('/status', 'status', self.newStatus)

    # UI Elements
    def create_ui(self, path):
        # Initialize
        path =  path + '/config.json'
        self._fps, self._ui = HomeConfigurationParser.parse(self._window, self._client, self._server, path)

        # Refresher
        self._timer = QTimer()
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self._timer.start(1000 / self._fps)

    def newStatus(self, request):
        self._status = request

    def update(self):
        # Update UI
        for elem in self._ui:
            elem.update(self._status)
        # Reset
        if self._status is not None:
            self._status = None
```

My problem is that by running monkey.path_all() the server does not process the requests anymore, in other words it basically ignores all the add_endpoint function calls. The server endpoints must be added at runtime I cannot add them directly in code through the @ above the functions.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

EDIT: Added more bits of code. The server runs side by side with the PyQt5 interface. The server is used to receive data to then update the PyQt5 interface accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The `add_url_rule` in the Flask source ([here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.1.x/src/flask/app.py#L1178)) has a `@setupmethod` decorator, which says "ignore me after the first request has been handled". (This is a key part of the `@app.before_first_request` mechanism.)

If you're starting up Flask in one thread, and later calling `add_endpoint` from another, your invoking thread is in a race with the first request to your app. There are also some serious issues with Thread safety that arise invoking methods that side-effect Flask internals from outside of the Flask main thread.

In your position, I'd rearrange to ensure that all of the `add_endpoint` calls happened before that `server.run` starts the app.

You may well still have a problem with monkeypatching, but I'd deal with this first.

Comment: I've added some more information so that it can be better understood what I'm doing. I've changed up the order of things such that the server is the last thing that is started up and the issue persists. 

If I start the server without the thread I can see in the console that requests are indeed being received (this freezes my pyqt app indefinitely if I leave http_server.serve_forever() whilst the server doesn't receive anything if I don't have that function in but does not freeze my pyqt app) but when I start it in its own thread I don't see anything happening in the console.

Comment: I have an app that starts Flask in a thread, but without monkey patching and without Qt. The only advice I have is to start with something like that, then add patching, and if that works, add Qt.

Comment: One difference, which might not be consequential: I start the Flask app in its own thread via `app.run`. If you do that and pass `debug=True` as an argument, you also need to pass `use_reloader=False`.